# Efficiently implementing ICollectionView for Filtering

Tags: c#, mvvm, filtering, icollectionview

I just implemented an `ICollectionView` into my first MVVM project and I have it working. I think, though, that the implementation could be better and more fluid. I'll post the code relating to my `ICollectionView` and if anybody can give me any tips or suggestions on how to streamline or improve it, please let me know. Here's my code:

```
private ICollectionView _advFilter;

public ICollectionView AdventurerFilter
{
    get { return _advFilter; }
    set
    {
        if (_advFilter != value)
        {
            _advFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => AdventurerFilter);
        }
    }
}


public MainViewModel()
{
    AdvNoFilter();
}


public void LoadGameExecute()
{
    //Serialization Logic

    AdvNoFilter();
}

public void ShowAllExecute()
{
    AdvNoFilter();
}

public void ShowEmployedExecute()
{
    AdvFilter(AdvStatus.Employed);
}

public void ShowAvailableExecute()
{
    AdvFilter(AdvStatus.Available);
}


void AdvFilter(AdvStatus status)
{
    AdventurerFilter = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Adventurers);
    AdventurerFilter.Filter = adv => ((Adventurer)adv).Status.Equals(status);
}

void AdvNoFilter()
{
    AdventurerFilter = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Adventurers);
    AdventurerFilter.Filter = null;
}
```

All of this is in my `MainViewModel`. The Show...Execute commands are bound to buttons in my `MainView` and the data is displayed in a `ListBox`, which is bound to `AdventurerFilter`. Like I sad before, it works, but I seriously doubt this could not be done more efficiently. Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: I should have mentioned this earlier but `Adventurers` is an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Why can't you use one of the built-in lists?  `ObservableCollection<>` can do what you need, or you could use `SortableObservableCollection` from here:  http://sortablecollection.codeplex.com/

Comment: `Adventurers` is an `ObservableCollection`. The link you posted doesn't cover filtering at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't an *implementation* of `ICollectionView`. It just uses default implementation, obtained through `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`.

You can cache obtained `ICollectionView`, there's no need to assign it every time you want to change the filter:

```
private ICollectionView _advFilter;

public MainViewModel()
{
    // assuming that Adventurers is ObservableCollection<Adventurer>
    _advFilter = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Adventurers);

    AdvNoFilter();
}

public void ShowEmployedExecute()
{
    AdvFilter(AdvStatus.Employed);
}

public void ShowAvailableExecute()
{
    AdvFilter(AdvStatus.Available);
}

void AdvFilter(AdvStatus status)
{
    _advFilter.Filter = adv => ((Adventurer)adv).Status.Equals(status);
    _advFilter.Refresh();
}

void AdvNoFilter()
{
    _advFilter.Filter = null;
    _advFilter.Refresh();
}
```